# Is it possible to monitor RAM usage for a specific software in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory, browser, opera, performance-monitor

I would like to know how much RAM is being used by a specific Application, for example: Exact RAM used by browser (ie:opera). The problem is that multiple instance are created by the browser so it's hard to do the calculation manually.

I know that TaskManager is displaying the total amount of RAM but this is not very helpfull.

So if you know any sort off software that can monitor this, please to share :).

Thanks

Comment: Configure perfmon to see usage over a period of time otherwise Task Manager will show you real time. I assume you want to see and look at what it uses over a period of time to see perhaps min, max, avg, etc. so start by researching how to setup and configure perfmon for such a task. Otherwise Resource Manager may help you from performance tab of task manager: https://i.imgur.com/GxSm5Ot.png

Comment: [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows that ram usage.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's hard to do the calculation manually.

You can use `tasklist` to get the memory usage.

Example:

```
> tasklist /fi "imagename eq opera*"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
opera.exe                     5444 Console                    1      78840 K
opera_crashreporter.exe       8404 Console                    1       6308 K
opera.exe                     8936 Console                    1      66708 K
opera.exe                     7804 Console                    1      70344 K
opera.exe                     2304 Console                    1      28200 K
opera.exe                     4612 Console                    1      73640 K
opera.exe                     8460 Console                    1      41168 K
```

The following batch file will do the adding up for you, and display the result every 60 seconds.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:start
set _mem=0
for /f "skip=3 usebackq tokens=5" %%i in (`tasklist /fi "imagename eq opera*"`) do (
  set /a _mem += %%i
  )
echo Total Memory = !_mem! K
rem wait 60 seconds
timeout 60 /nobreak
goto :start
endlocal
```

Example:

```
> test
Total Memory = 365464K

Waiting for  0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
Total Memory = 365216K

Waiting for 51 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.